# Can i add emoji symbols to subject line using FreeMarker templates

Tags: templates, notifications, teamcity, freemarker, emoji

Can i add emoji symbols to subject line using FreeMarker templates?
I am using Team City continues integration tool that sends me notifications when my builds have failed or succeeded

Team City are using "FreeMarker templates" for their notification system.
I want that the notifications emails that are sent from the team city server will have emoji icons in the subject line (i.e. Smiley for passed builds)

I know that i can edit the FreeMarker templates in order to change the content of these notification emails, but i can not get it to send Emojis

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as your e-mail subject lines use UTF-8 encoding (which is not up to FreeMarker), you can insert any emoji characters. Even ridiculous things like ,  etc. has a character code. Simply copy-paste them into your template; if everything uses UTF-8, they should come through. Depending one the browser and the e-mail client they can render differently, but as the subject line is plain text, you can't specify actual images.